# Ender 3 + SKR 1.4 + Marlin 2.0.x bugfix - what bed size/min/max positions should I use?

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, homing, y-axis, skr-v1.4

On my Ender 3, it seems that the Y-axis can only move forward 220 mm after which the carriage will hit the tensioner. This seems repeatable so I don't think it's a hardware issue (unless it's expected that the nozzle can reach all the way to the front edge).

I'm unclear, with this information, how I can center my nozzle properly so that it is 117.5 mm from each edge, and that the corner leveling feature works as expected (by default, configured to be 30 mm from each edge).

Comment: Hi Alex. Are you able to properly home the printer, or not? I understood that after you home, the Y movement is limited by your hardware setup (mounted tensioner) to only 220 mm. But you would like to have full 235 mm. What tensioner is installed there? From your description I could read that there is a collision, so I would say it is a hardware issue... If you can home the printer, you can limit the print area.

Answer (score 2):

The Ender 3 has a printable area of 220x220x250 mm according to the specifications. So, there is nothing wrong. Sometimes heated beds are slightly larger than the actual print area. E.g. 235x235 mm or 310x310 mm. For centering the nozzle to the build plate, you should look into "[How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](/q/6375)" or "[Recalibrating Home-position](/q/6399).